# Autocomplete not working with some mobile browsers when using non-latin characters

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, character, mobile-safari, latin

I use jQuery 1.7.2 with jQuery UI autocomplete 1.8.22 and it works fine with all pc based browsers

On mobile browsers other than Chrome, when the search terms are using non-latin characters (let's say greek) other mobile browsers such as Firefox and Safari fail.

Are there any known issues I should be aware that affects mobile Firefox and Safari?

Comment: Which autocomplete. Please make a jsfiddle.net or similar and please pay attention to your negatives "not with latin characters, mobile browsers only (firefox and safari) but not chrome, can not work." - too many nots. You mean Mobile FX and Safari does not work but mobile chrome works?

Comment: Yes this is what i mean, chrome works but no the other mobile browsers, all the pc browsers editions working fine. The problem exists only with no latin characters.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are using. jQuery mobile? jQuery UI autocomplete? What versions? Which mobiles use Firefox?

Comment: i use jQuery UI autocomplete version 1.8.22, with jquery 1.7.2, i test with an android os mobile

Comment: The same thing. Doesn't work on mobile Firefox but works on Chrome. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions i have found for solve the problem is

```
$('#element').on('input', function(){
    $(this).autocomplete("search", $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Your solution did not work for me :( The `#element` is the ID of input right? And the `search`? Is this inside the listener or outside? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that this version of ui autocomplete is not optimized for input events on mobile browsers. Mobile firefox doesn't support keyup and keydown events. In later versions of jQuery ui this problem is fixed.

Here is the link on jquery forum describing this problem.
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8263